# Key event background change in canvas

Tags: button, canvas, colors, background

I'm trying to add a keydown event in Canvas that will change the background color to a random one, so far I'm not getting any errors but my function isn't working.

This is it so far, I think I may have to tell the function to apply it to the canvas background? Not too sure about my own judgment ><

```
    window.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 40) {
    fillBackgroundColor();
  }
});


function fillBackgroundColor() {
        var colors = ["red", "green", "blue", "orange", "purple", "yellow"];
        var color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is generating a new random color and storing the color in a local variabble but otherwise is doing nothing with the color. The code needs to repaint the canvas with the color. Assuming that you have a canvas with an id of "canvas"...

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

then the fillBackgroundColor() method could be changed to something like...

```
function fillBackgroundColor() {
    var colors = ["red", "green", "blue", "orange", "purple", "yellow"];
    var color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.fillStyle = color;
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
```

Note that this code completely repaints the canvas with the random background color. If you had any foreground objects already painted on the canvas then you would also have to repaint those foreground objects.

Comment: I do have shapes and such painted on the canvas beforehand, is there no way to just paint the background?

Or could I write a function that redraws my shapes as the button is pressed as well?

Comment: Canvas uses a painters model. Think of a painter using brushes to apply paint to a physical canvas. Each new brush stroke adds new paint on top of any existing paint. There is not a way to replace the earliest layers of paint. A typical approach is to have a single scene rendering function that paints your whole scene (including background and foreground). When you need to change something (e.g. background color), you can call this scene rendering function to redraw everything.